# Can we make a list of "favorite questions"?

Tags: feature-request, search, bookmarks

I found myself difficulty in searching for "favorite questions"; can we place the list in the profile view?

Comment: Isn't it already, like [your favorite questions](http://stackoverflow.com/users/5260005/sameer-joshi?tab=favorites)?

Answer (score 2):

You can already search in your favorite questions; just use the following parameter:

```
infavorites:mine
```

https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=infavorites%3Amine

Otherwise, if you just need the list, it is already included in your profile as @rene mentions. Heck, even *we* can view a list of *your* favorite questions.